# Return On a Spread

Tags: returns, spread

This is a beginner level question.

I have a $spread = aluminium - 0.7*lead $

$s = a - 0.7*l$

I have two methods to calculate return on this spread:

$ return = (s_t - s_{t-1})/(a_t + 0.7*l_t) $

which is nothing but:

$return = change/value_{investment} $

or

$ return = a_t - a_{t-1}/a_{t-1} - 0.7*(l_t - l_{t-1)/l_{t-1} $

which is nothing but:

$return_{aluminium} - 0.7*return_{lead} $

Which return definition is correct assuming I am taking 2 investment along a spread that is long in $1$ unit of aluminium and correspondingly short in $0.7$ unit of lead and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

> Which return definition is correct

Neither one, and it appears that you are actually interested in the *rate* of return. In the first definition of rate of return, the denominator should be $s_{t-1}$.

In the second definition, the ratios do not really compute the return of $a$ and $l$. Each term somewhat resembles the logarithm property, except that you are missing the logarithm function in each term. Even if you applied the logarithm function, your calculations would fail as soon as the positions in $a$ and $l$ differ in magnitude.

Comment: Please check my edit, also I cannot add s(t-1) in the denominator since it can take negative values

Comment: Precisely because the spread could take zero and negative values, it does not make sense to compute a return. Why do you need a return?

Comment: @DhruvMahajan (1) It is unclear to me what you meant to change in the edit. (2) I am not suggesting you to *add* $s_{t-1}$ in the denominator, but that you *replace* the denominator with $s_{t-1}$ instead: Rates of return must have the *previous* (or initial) period in the denominator. (3) Dividing by $a_t+0.7*l_t$ contradicts your premise of having a short position in *lead*. (4) In line with Alex C's comment, if $s_{t-1}$ were non-positive, then you would have no funds to invest at time=$t$.

Comment: if you purchase the actual commodity, then there is a point in considering your return measures (subject to Alex C's comment). often times in commodities though, these spreads are traded via futures, i.e. you do not put down the notional value of the commodity, but just a fraction of that, plus you may get some margin netting between long and short positions, so you would see returns very differently

Comment: @ZRH What you describe sounds like trading on margin. This is not based on spreads but on leverage. So you deposit a fraction (the margin), fill the rest with debt and buy the commodity. Even CFDs are working on the difference like a common investment. And Futures as well. Spread, for me, means the spread between bid and ask prices or between two assets (e.g. WTI and Brent). But imho the definition of a return on spreads could lead to problems (as already outlined).

Comment: Well I meant trading via futures (which of course also means you obtain leverage), in which case I struggle to see the value of the standard formulae given above

Comment: @ZRH But even then you would calculate the return on the initial investment made (i.e. the margin) and not on spreads. The point of the original question is building some kind of time series of spread changes (I avoid using the term return here) which could lead to problems for price parity (spread = 0) or a spread flip (negative spread).

Comment: I need to calculate the return on this spread because I'm trading it as a part of a pairs trading strategy, so I can backtest my cumalative returns on this spread trade and calculate Sharpe ratio. That's why I was thinking either I can take this spread as portfolio of 2 assets and use the formula R = w1*R1 + w2*R2 which would give me the second return formula or I could formulate return using my total investment which is 1 unit of aluminium + absolute value of shorting 0.7 units of lead which would lead me to the first formula

Comment: @DhruvMahajan I see. But for pairs trading you would consider a relative spread (aluminum/0.7lead) rather than the absolute spread (aluminum-0.7lead). The relative spread makes things more feasible as it avoids negative or zero spreads.